# How to upload a git repo to gerrit?

Tags: linux, git, msysgit, gerrit

I installed the gerrit service on a ubuntu server,and my PC as client.
I created a git repo on my PC(with msysgit),and the question is :how can I upload the git repo to the Ubuntu server?Should I do some work on Ubuntu server first(i just installed gerrit and git service )?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to create the project on the Gerrit server using [`gerrit create-project`](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/cmd-create-project.html).

Next, edit the project permissions if necessary to add the following for your user (Administrators group, probably):

- Create reference
- Forge committer identity
- Forge author identity

This allows you to upload an existing history, perhaps committed by different people, bypassing the need to review every commit you select.

Finally, push your code:

```
git remote add gerrit gerritserver:project
git push gerrit master:refs/heads/master
```